# Upgraded mongodb 2.6 -> 3.6 and seeing errors: "Sessions collection is not set up..."

Tags: mongodb

I had a replica set running on MongoDB version 2.6 and upgraded to 3.6 (2.6 -> 3.0 -> 3.2 -> 3.4 -> 3.6).

The cluster is working fine for my normal operations.

```
rs.result()
...
"ok" : 1
```

I'm trying to connect a tool that's using MongoDB Java Driver and is getting this error:

```
Sessions are not supported by the MongoDB cluster to which this client is connected
```

Might be unrelated but I'm seeing this in my MongoDB server log:

```
2023-03-03T01:19:44.298+0000 I CONTROL  [LogicalSessionCacheReap] Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions reap interval: config.system.sessions does not exist
```

When searching about this error, it suggests that replica set hasn't been initialized. But I already have a replica set that I've upgraded from v2.6.
I wouldn't want to re-initialize as this existing replica set is in use.

What might be the issue here? and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Impressing - no upgrade for 10 years!

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow all these upgrade procedures step-by-step?

- https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/
- https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/3.2-upgrade/
- https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/3.4-upgrade-replica-set/
- https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/3.6-upgrade-replica-set/

Perhaps you have to wait some time between the steps to have all tasks completed.

What you can try is to drop the `local` database and initialize the ReplicaSet again

```
db.getSiblingDB('local').dropDatabase()
rs.init()
```

Then you can add again the other members, they will trigger an initial sync.

However, I guess you like to upgrade even to current MongoDB version 6.0. In this case an `monogexport` or `mongodump` and then import into a fresh MongoDB version 6.0 database would be faster and more reliable.